# Iphone simulator is not having phone shape

Tags: iphone, ios

Iphone Simulator, in my Mac system, is not having regular phone shape like

[image: Regular Phone Image]

Instead it looks like a window

[image: Shape of Iphone simulator in my Mac System]

When I give iOS Simulator->Hardware->rotate left, it gives a irregular shape

[image: Shape when rotated left]

My Mac system Specification is

OSX:  version 10.6.8

xcode: version 3.2.6

iOS:  version 4.3

How this can  be corrected?

Comment: Try to update Xcode and SDK to the latest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simulator is displayed this way if your screen is too small to fit the full version. Are you using something with a relatively small screen, like a MacBook Air?

If so it may not be a bug (well, the second screenshot is, obviously, but the first may not be).

Also check what Hardware > Device settings your simulator is using. If it's set to iPhone (Retina), try changing it to just iPhone, which should fit on your screen better.

Also, check the Window > Scale and see if it lets you change it.

Comment: I checked Hardware->device, its set to iphone and Window->scale also not helping.

Comment: Better follow the others' advice and reinstall the SDK then.

Comment: It was problem with screen resolution. When i changed to higher resolution( from 800*600 to 1024*768), iOS simulator is working fine... Thanks @Nick LockWood

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is to reinstall xcode and ios sdk

Answer (score 0):

**You change simulator shape for iPhone device**

***MacBook Air***

Simulator settings -> Window -> Show device bezels